# Devise and Stateless tokens in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I got an API that I have developed using Rails 3 and Devise. I am using tokens (token_authenticatable) for authentication for requests made to the API from a client. I want to be able to switch between users in the requests just be replacing the token.

I heard about a setting called :stateless_token (boolean) but I cannot figure out where to put this setting. Is there another way?

If found the token_authenticatable here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/token_authenticatable.rb

If found info about the stateless_token here:

http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable

Answer (score 13):

`stateless_token` is deprecated as of now. This is the new form (it allows more auth strategies to be stateless):

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.skip_session_storage = [:token_auth]
```

Comment: With Devise 2.1.3, Rails 3.1.1 I was getting the error message: `undefined method `stateless_token=' for Devise:Module`. This change fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can also edit the file /config/initializers/devise.rb and put (or uncomment, if already there) the following line:

```
config.stateless_token = true
```

Comment: As noted elsewhere, this is now deprecated. Use the config.skip_session_storage = [:token_auth] option

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it wasn't back then when I replied :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be an option in your devise_for line in the routes file.

```
devise_for :users, :stateless_token => true
```

Let me know if that works,
In this [page of documentation for devise](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable) it says that "TokenAuthenticatable adds the following options to devise_for:" with stateless token being one of them.

Also here is a link to the [devise_for documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method)